# Multi chained drop down group

Tags: php, html

I have a select list like this to select car branch:

```
<td style="width: 243px">Branch:</td>
<td>
    <select name="Branch" style="width: 235px">
        <option selected="">TOYOTA</option>
        <option>HONDA</option>
        <option>NISSAN</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

I have three other select lists for name of car:

- One for 'TOYOTA type' contain for example COROLLA, CAMRY,RAV4, and
  others
- One for 'HONDA type' contain for example CIVIC, ACCORD, others
- One for 'NISSAN type' contain for example

If a user selects TOYOTA the 'TOYOTA' type select list will appear only without showing other BRANCH Cars. How can I do this?

Comment: Why must this be in PHP? It would make sense to implement this in javascript.

Comment: You can do this by adding a javascript callback to your branch combo box that will programmatically set the available values for your "model" combobox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jquery and show() hide() properties. That will work in every browser.

```
$(document).ready(function($){

  $('#TOYOTA').click(function() {
    $('#BMWmodels').hide();
    $('#VOLVOmodels').hide();
    $('#TOYOTAmodels').show();
  });
});
```

Then let CSS do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the car brand select, once you select the car brand you could make an AJAX call to a script which will return a JSON with a list of cars from that brand. You decode the JSON and create a select (or populate a hidden select which you then display) with the brand's cars. For this you can use Jquery or Prototype javascript frameworks.

Another option is to submit the form when the brand of the car is chosen and add the new select from PHP.